# How to write dropdown selections to mysql prior to posting the form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I run a simple form collecting 4 values, three of the values are listed in a dropdown. I'm wondering if I can write the values selected by a user to my mysql table prior to submitting the form.

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="search" action="" method="POST">
<input id="field1" type="text" name="to" value="">
<select name="day">
<option value="">Day</option>
<option value="1"> 1</option>
<option value="2"> 2</option>
<option value="3"> 3</option>
</select>

<select name="cym">
<option selected="" value="">Month</option>
<option value="2012-12">December 2012</option>
<option value="2013-01">January 2013</option>
<option value="2013-02">February 2013</option>
</select>

<select name="nights">
<option value="">Nights</option>
<option value="1"> 1</option>
<option value="2"> 2</option>
<option value="3"> 3</option>
</select>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('search').submit();">Search!</button>`
```

So, once the user selects the 'day', I want to write the value to the mysql, once the user select the 'cym' I want to write the value to the mysql and so on.

Can this be realized and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery you can do something like this:

```
 $("#cym").change(function () {
     $.ajax({
            url: 'serverUrl.php',
            success: function(data) {
             // nothing to be done here
            }
            });
          });
```

The `<select name="cym">` would become `<select id="cym">` for the selector  `$("#cym")` to work. This, of course, can be achieved by using raw Javascript and if that's your preferred approach you can have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first .

Answer (score 1):

You can bind some onChange events to the select elements. You can easily use jQuery for that. Look at http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the link to the corresponding documentation! The script now works perfectly!